# Delete Command C# + SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, c#-4.0

I'm performing a command to erase data from a DataGridView
But I can not make it work, I just want to select a line and erase it

In addition to programming a button that says "Delete" so that when you click on it, the selected data in the DataGridView will be deleted

I need really help 
I am lost

My Table is "Person"
My Column is "ID"

Instances

```
    {SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;}

    public string Del(int ID)
    {
        string ouk = "Delete Work";
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Person Where = ID )", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ouk = "Bad character:" + ex.ToString();
        }

        return ouk;
    }
```

---

For Button Erase at DataGridView

```
    private void buttondel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(c.Del(TBID));
    }
```

Comment: is your datagrid databind

Comment: and how you are getting TBID value

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that your SQL query is malformed and that you're not passing the ID to the query:

```
"Delete From Person Where = ID )"
```

One side of the equality check is missing, and you have an unexpected closing bracket.

You should change your query to accept a parameter:

```
"Delete From Person Where ID = @id"
```

and then pass the parameter to your command:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
```

So it becomes:

```
try
{
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Person Where ID = @id", cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ouk = "Bad character:" + ex.ToString();
}
```

I've taken the liberty of wrapping SqlCommand in a `using` statement so that it's disposed once we're done with it.

Comment: up voted for a good explanation and not telling off the OP for how many mistakes he had